# Speed when pulling a sled up a hill

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

You pull a sled up a hill. You slow down as you get tired near the top. Friction is significant. Ft= 100 N Ff= 30 N m = 15 kg The sled moves 10 m vertically and 37 m along the surface of the hill. You start off at 3.4 m/s. What is your speed at the top?

I used the equation: Ek1+Wext=Ek2+Eg2, substituted in all of the given values and ended up with v2>v1 which makes no sense...

Comment: On flat ground, if you pull harder than friction, the sled will speed up. Did you forget gravity?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I calculated the force of gravity at the second point. There wouldn't be a need to calculate it at the start due to path independence?

Answer (score 1):

Using conservation of energy will certainly yield the correct results.

$$\sum\mathrm{PE}+\mathrm{KE}+W_\mathrm{other \; forces}=\sum\mathrm{PE}'+\mathrm{KE}'$$

Make sure you account for the following:

- The work by friction will be negative, and remember that you're considering the $37\;\mathrm m$ distance.
- Do not forget the gained gravitational potential energy, $\mathrm {PE}'=mgh$.
- Do not forget the work **you** do by pulling the sled up -- again, the distance you're considering is the $37\;\mathrm m$, and I would assume that the tension force is in the same direction as the displacement.